# Deploy icu libraries when linking a cmake project with Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5, icu

I've the following `CMakeLists.txt` for creating a little application:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5.0)

project (sampleapp)

# Setting project flags
set (CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/lib)
set (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/lib)
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/bin)
set (CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set (CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Finding needed packages
find_package (Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package (Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package (Qt5Gui REQUIRED)

# Setting project files
include_directories (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
file (GLOB_RECURSE PROJECT_SRC *.cpp)

# Creating project
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SRC})

# Linking dependencies
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} somelibrary Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Gui Qt5::Core)
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::Widgets> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::Gui> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::Core> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
```

When I run it and then build the application the Qt dlls are copied into target folder. In particular I copy:

- `Qt5Core.dll`
- `Qt5Gui.dll`
- `Qt5Widgets.dll`

When I run the application it does not start anyway because the ICU libraries needed for Qt are not copied. When I start the application, Windows tells me that following libraries are missing:

- `icuin53.dll`
- `icuuc53.dll`

If I copy these libraries manually from Qt insallation folder it works (ok, I've an error regarding "platform plugins windows" missing but it's another story).

Is there a way to copy the icu libraries in a standard way, like the post build commands that I'm using for copying libraries? Or what's the best way to copy them in a transparent way, if possible (CMake can know what are dependencies of Qt and copy them where Qt are needed)?

Comment: `CMake can know what are dependencies of Qt and copy them where Qt are needed` - CMake itself has no functionality to copy all depdendent libraries.

Comment: So what's the best cmake way to copy these libraries along with Qt ones?

Comment: As far as I understand, CMake treats **copiing 3d-party libraries** into the directory with executable as a **bad design**. From the developer's point of view, 3d-party libraries should be installed *system-widely*, so they can be loaded from any executable. While I understand your problem is actual, I don't know a decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of copying each dll by hand, you can install all Qt dependencies using `windeployqt`, the tool provided with Qt for deployment on Windows.

You can first declare `windeployqt` as an imported executable:

```
find_package(Qt5
    # ...
)

if(Qt5_FOUND AND WIN32 AND TARGET Qt5::qmake AND NOT TARGET Qt5::windeployqt)
    get_target_property(_qt5_qmake_location
        Qt5::qmake IMPORTED_LOCATION
    )

    execute_process(
        COMMAND "${_qt5_qmake_location}" -query QT_INSTALL_PREFIX
        RESULT_VARIABLE return_code
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE qt5_install_prefix
        OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )

    set(imported_location "${qt5_install_prefix}/bin/windeployqt.exe")

    if(EXISTS ${imported_location})
        add_executable(Qt5::windeployqt IMPORTED)

        set_target_properties(Qt5::windeployqt PROPERTIES
            IMPORTED_LOCATION ${imported_location}
        )
    endif()
endif()
```

Now the imported executable can be used as follows:

```
add_executable(foo
    # ...
)

if(TARGET Qt5::windeployqt)
    add_custom_command(TARGET foo
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove_directory "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/windeployqt"
        COMMAND set PATH=%PATH%$<SEMICOLON>${qt5_install_prefix}/bin
        COMMAND Qt5::windeployqt --dir "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/windeployqt" "$<TARGET_FILE:foo>"
    )

    install(
        DIRECTORY
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/windeployqt/"
        DESTINATION ${FOO_INSTALL_RUNTIME_DESTINATION}
    )
endif()
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, this is the tool that I need... I need only to create a cmake function for handling all this and put it in a separate file, so I can use it across all my projects without bloating. Thanks again.

Comment: Can't you just replace `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:foo>/$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:foo>` with `$<TARGET_FILE:foo>`? The latter is the full path to the target, that is also what you are trying to construct with the former. Am I wrong?

Comment: @skypjack looks like you're right. I edited my answer. Thx :)